# Is it possible to install software remotely on my clients via a application running on my server, having the installs be triggered by HTTP requests?

Tags: windows, installation, remote, automation, automated-install

First, I have to say that I have no experience with servers or infrastructure whatsoever. Here's the situation, basically I have a huge number of client machines that I want to quickly deploy software to. These clients run Windows and are connected to a main server (running Windows Server, but we can change to other OS if need be).

I would like to know if there's a way to use a software on the server that can remotely and silently install applications (Adobe Reader, Flash Player, Microsoft Office, Skype, etc) on the clients. Beyond that I would also need to send the install commands to the server via some internet protocol.

Let's say, via HTTP I send the name of the client (PC0001), the software to be installed ("skype") and some authentication information to the software, these instructions trigger the process of silently installing Skype on that client machine.

There are tools that can be used to accomplish this? What are they?

Comment: Check out WSUS, you need to use other ports for that thou.

Comment: You can remotely trigger a GP update and install applications that way. Or use configuration managment tools like puppet or salt or microsoft's system center for configuration manager, or maybe use desired state configuration with powershell. But none of those options will work out if you don't know what you're doing. Maybe hire someone for the job?

Answer (score 0):

I think you are looking for some "Client Management Software". There are differnent players on the market for things like that. Most of them aren't for free but will bring you many other improvements like inventory of the clients, remote console, provisioning, patch management and so on.

Considerable players are LANDesk oder Baramundi for example... But there are many more if you google for "Client Management"...

But i think the most of these products have some kind of software client which you have to install on the pc's.

hope this helps.